# How to combine members of flags when values are tuples

Tags: python, enums

I have an enum Flag defined like this:

```
@unique
@verify(CONTINUOUS)
class DaysEnum(IntFlag):
    ONE = (1, "One Day")
    TWO = (2, "Two Days")
    THREE = (3, "Three Days")
    FOUR = (4, "Four Days")
    FIVE = (5, "Five Days")
    SIX = (6, "Six Days")
    SEVEN = (7, "Seven Days")
    EVEN_DAYS = (TWO | FOUR | SIX, "Even Days")

    def __init__(self, value, label) -> None:
        self.label = label

    def __new__(cls, value: int, label: str):
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.label = label
        return obj
```

According to [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#combining-members-of-flag) I can combine members of enums when inheriting from the class `enum.Flag`. When running this code, I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'tuple'.` The syntax of how I defined the member `EVEN_DAYS` seems to be wrong.

What is the proper syntax to combine the members of `EVEN_DAYS` considering that the values of `DaysEnum` are tuples?

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you don't need `__init__` because you are setting `.label` in `__new__`.

The problem you are running into is that the names `ONE`, `TWO`, etc., are just tuples during parsing -- they don't get converted from tuple to member until after the entire class is parsed.

In other words, `EVEN_DAYS = TWO | FOUR| SIX` would work after flag creation, but not during.

Comment: When I run the code with `EVEN_DAYS = TWO | FOUR| SIX` I still get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'tuple' `. In vscode, pylance complains on the other hand: `Argument missing for parameter "label"PylancereportCallIssue`

Comment: Regarding the use of `__init__`: When i leave the `__init__`definition out, pylance complains: `Cannot assign member "label" for type "DaysEnum*"
  Member "label" is unknownPylancereportAttributeAccessIssue`

Comment: It feels to me that I am trying to use Flags in a way they are not supposed to be used. My current workaround is to use `@property`instead to receive ÈVEN_DAYS`.